# Can we replace the MAC address with an IP address?

Tags: network-core

In the OSI model, Layer 2 uses MAC addresses, and Layer 3 uses IP addresses. Suggest and explain a way to replace MAC addresses with IP addresses, such that a MAC address is no longer required, and each device in a LAN uses only one single IP address?

Comment: This sounds very much like homework....

Answer (score 1):

While studying the OSI model, you missed the point about the layers being independent. Layer-2, which has addresses, encapsulates layer-3, which has addresses, and that encapsulates layer-4, which has addresses.

Having independent layers simplifies things. For instance, you can have ethernet at layer-2, or any number of other layer-2 protocols, each of which have their own addressing. Whichever layer-2 protocol you use can carry IPv4, or any of the layer-3 protocols.

We now have IPv6. If you only had a single address for layer-2 and layer-3, it would be very difficult to have networks which run both IPv4 and IPv6. Ethernet switches use MAC addresses, and are ignorant (with a few exceptions) to the layer-3 protocol carried as payload in the ethernet frames. This allows a single network to carry any number of layer-3 protocols simultaneously.

You probably assume the whole world uses ethernet and IP, but that is not the case. Those two protocols now dominate, but each were developed, independently, around the same time, and each are maintained by different standards bodies. Ethernet was primarily used for IPX for a long time, while IP ran on WAN circuits to connect universities.

As far as having a single IP address on each device goes, IPv6 not only allows multiple addresses on a single device, but it requires it for communication with any device not on your LAN.